# How import a whole database with a sql script exported from another database in Oracle sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle, import, export

I just want to migrate a db from server to my local machine.Too much trouble, it is sucked now...I got a sql script with the export tool of sql developer for the whole database in server,then i try to run it in my new empty local db, run the sql file in the editor, but nothing happened at all, no error, no result..Anyone can give me some idea?

Thanks

Comment: How big is your sql script? Maybe it's too large? Better way to migrate data is to use exp/expdp and impa/impdp.

Answer (score 0):

@Leon Stack Leak
Could you please expand on your question abit, including the syntax you have attempted for your migration. Also nice to know what database server product you are using (e.g Oracle, or MySQL, or other option). Let us also know the environment/platform, i.e Linux,Windoes etc

If you are exporting the whole schema and assuming you are using Oracle, the best way as Paradox said, is to use the Export and Import Data Pump utilities. To export the database from your currently existing schema, the syntax will be:

```
expdp username/password DIRECTORY=mydirectory DUMPFILE=mydumpfile.dmp SCHEMAS=schema1,schema2 LOGFILE=exportlog1.log
```

To import it back, the syntax will be

```
impdp username/password DIRECTORY=mydirectory DUMPFILE=mydumpfile.dmp LOGFILE=importlog1.log
```

Also worth noting that the syntax for the import can be expanded to include more powerful options like remapping schemas,transform OIDs etc.